Unstable plans when two first index columns have NULL values in all rows
I have a weird case of a query that takes long to execute despite having good matching index. The thing is that the values of the first 2 columns in a non-clustered index are NULL in all rows. (For context, it became like that after archiving old data from old business processes). The query has WHERE clause on these 2 columns using equality and non-NULL values, therefore it should be easy for SQL Server to prepare a good plan using index seek+lookup especially that the data being looked for doesn't exist, so estimates are 0 or 1 row.
Unfortunately the query is very sensitive to changes in the table, not even to statistics auto-update or data skew. I suspect it could be a bug in optimizer where it cannot make use of a single-step statistic histograms where NULL is the only value in range. I'm not sure I explored all options, though, therefore I would like someone to look at it. The production server is 2017, but I've prepared this repro in 2022, and behavior is identical in these 2 versions.
The table in production contains 35 million rows and around 60 columns and is being updated (mostly insert+update) around 3000 rows in 1 hour, so not much of write traffic, mostly reads.
Is there anything I missed? Or is it a real bug?
Thank you in advance.
use tempdb;
go

-- The simplest repro of the issue.

-- Just in case you wondered if it's enabled. It's not needed, but included for your reference.
alter database tempdb set auto_create_statistics on;
alter database tempdb set auto_update_statistics on;

drop table if exists t1;

create table t1 (
  ID int identity(1,1) not null
      primary key clustered,
  c2 int null,
  c3 varchar(16) null,
  c4 int null,
  c5 varchar(128) null,
  -- in prod there are ~50 more columns
);


-- The actual prod index has 4 columns with explicit ID PK at the end.
create index ix_test on t1 (c2, c3, c4, ID);

-- The prod table contains ~35 million rows. The issue occurs with much smaller
-- number of rows so I only use 1 million here to not waste your time playing with it.
--
-- It happens that in prod all rows have NULL values in c2 and c3.
insert into t1 (c4, c5)
select top (1000*1000) crypt_gen_random(2), 'a'
from sys.all_columns ac1, sys.all_columns ac2;

-- At this point the query uses the index (see the plan).
declare @0 int = 100;      -- value that may or may not exist
select ID, c2, c3, c4, c5  -- and all remaining columns in prod
from t1
where c2 = @0 and c3 = 'x' -- 'x' is a value that may or may not exist
order by c2, c3, c4, ID;   -- this is the exact order of the index
go

-- But with "option (recompile)" it does the full scan of the clustered index
-- and has awful estimates.
declare @0 int = 100;
select ID, c2, c3, c4, c5
from t1
where c2 = @0 and c3 = 'x'
order by c2, c3, c4, ID
option (recompile);
go

-- The same issue also occurs when not using parameters.
select ID, c2, c3, c4, c5
from t1
where c2 = 100 and c3 = 'x'
order by c2, c3, c4, ID
option (recompile);

-- Now let's update statistics to be as great as possible.
update statistics t1 with fullscan, maxdop=1;

-- After which it picks the right index and have great estimates with or
-- without "option (recompile)".
declare @0 int = 100;
select ID, c2, c3, c4, c5
from t1
where c2 = @0 and c3 = 'x'
order by c2, c3, c4, ID
option (recompile);

-- Insert only a tiny bit of more data. It does not trigger auto update of the
-- statistics.
insert into t1 (c4, c5)
select top (10) 1, crypt_gen_random(2)
from sys.all_columns ac1, sys.all_columns ac2;

-- And now it again does the full scan even when not using the hint nor the
-- @parameter.
select ID, c2, c3, c4, c5
from t1
where c2 = 100 and c3 = 'x'
order by c2, c3, c4, ID;
go

-- If the above gave you seek+lookup, this one will not:
declare @0 int = 100;
select ID, c2, c3, c4, c5
from t1
where c2 = @0 and c3 = 'x'
order by c2, c3, c4, ID
option (recompile);

-- When using the index hint it works fine, but has awful estimates.
select ID, c2, c3, c4, c5
from t1
where c2 = 100 and c3 = 'x'
order by c2, c3, c4, ID
option (table hint (t1, index (ix_test)));

-- I would expect it to just always use the index seek + lookup. The query
-- should always be fast. It's easy to determine that there's no data
-- satisfying the filter.

-- When you check the stats histogram, there's none.
declare @stats_id int = (
  select stats_id from sys.stats
  where [object_id] = object_id('t1') and name = 'ix_test');
select * from sys.dm_db_stats_histogram(object_id('t1'), @stats_id);

/* In SSMS you can see that there's only 1 step:
Statistics for INDEX 'ix_test'.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Name             Updated     Rows   Rows Sampled   Steps  Density  Average Key Length  String Index
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ix_test   Sep 9 2024 4:59PM  1000000        1000000       1        0                   8            NO  1000000  0

 All Density  Average Length         Columns
--------------------------------------------
           1               0              c2
           1               0          c2, c3
1.525879E-05               4      c2, c3, c4
       1E-06               8  c2, c3, c4, ID

Histogram Steps
RANGE_HI_KEY  RANGE_ROWS  EQ_ROWS  DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS  AVG_RANGE_ROWS
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                       0  1000000                    0               1

so the optimizer has the knowledge that all rows have NULL values, and
that there's nothing else in the table, it just is unable to use that
information in some cases.
*/



EDIT: This is the query plan when using OPTION (RECOMPILE):

and this is the plan without the hint. I missed the fact that it has been parameterized despite passing the literal value in the string:


I hate to approve my own answers, but this time I think I got it right.
After 3 days of tinkering with this issue I came to the conclusion that SQL Server gets lost with single-step statistics. After updating values in column c2 to -1 and c3 to 'a' in all rows, the issue still occurred, so it's not specific to NULLs.
Until the table becomes large, this is not a problem. But when the size is substantial, you're starting to notice it.
After adding just 1000 rows with some non-NULL values in c2, the issue went away entirely. In the production system we un-archived this tiny amount of old data, updated statistics and poof! Plans are stable and have seek+lookup with estimated number of rows around 1 as expected.
A side note: PostgreSQL 16 and SQLite handle that scenario just fine. Tried up to 30 million in size.
Thank you all for your answers and comments.


-- When you check the stats histogram, there's none.

That's a bug in sys.dm_db_stats_histogram. DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS shows the NULL row correctly (this is what SSMS uses). The original problem with sys.dm_db_stats_histogram was that it never displayed the extra NULL step. They fixed that, but it still doesn't show a NULL step if that's the only step. They've shown no interest in fixing that.

...the first 2 columns in a non-clustered index are NULL in all rows. (For context, it became like that after archiving old data from old business processes). The query has WHERE clause on these 2 columns using equality and non-NULL values, therefore it should be easy for SQL Server to prepare a good plan using index seek+lookup especially that the data being looked for doesn't exist, so estimates are 0 or 1 row.

Yes, but that's just a bananas scenario. It's just plain weird to create an index with a leading column all the same. The histogram (built only on the first column) is almost useless. Yes, it gives a good estimate (SQL Server never estimates 0 rows, except in one narrow case no one cares about) when the statistics are freshly built.

so the optimizer has the knowledge that all rows have NULL values, and
that there's nothing else in the table, it just is unable to use that
information in some cases.

When modifications are made to the underlying table, SQL Server records this fact and uses it to modify the histogram and its selectivity estimations in general. It knows nothing about the values used in those modifications.
What should it assume? That the new values are all NULL? Maybe, but it doesn't. There's no reason to think new values will be NULL just because existing ones are. We're firmly entrenched in guesswork territory here. If SQL Server assumed all future values fell within the existing histogram, other people would complain about that assumption.
Another modelling assumption is that users generally write queries to find data that exists. This may or may not always be a good assumption, but it is what it is. You're looking for data you know doesn't exist. You query simply doesn't fit the model.
All in all, it's no wonder you're getting unstable plans and estimates. You're asking crazy questions of the optimizer and giving it no useful information to work with. SQL Server isn't magic and can't guess it's operating in a crazy situation. Something about the design or supporting indexes and queries will need to change.
If you can't do anything else, at least tell the optimizer those columns are always NULL:
ALTER TABLE dbo.t1
    WITH CHECK ADD
    CONSTRAINT 
        [CK dbo.t1 c2 IS NULL]
    CHECK (c2 IS NULL);

ALTER TABLE dbo.t1
    WITH CHECK ADD
    CONSTRAINT 
        [CK dbo.t1 c3 IS NULL]
    CHECK (c3 IS NULL);

All your plans will then look like this, since there's no need to access the table at all:

For what it's worth, your script always results in a seek plus lookup plan for me, testing on SQL Server 2022 CU14 using compatibility level 160 and the default cardinality estimator.
You could always use a FORCESEEK hint, directly on the query or via Query Store or plan guides. I don't know why you would care about cardinality estimates if you get the seek plus lookup plan, but maybe that information is simply missing from the question.
Regardless, the answer to your question is no, it's not a SQL Server bug.

You can create a partial index with only the NOT NULL values:
create index ix_test on t1 (c2, c3, c4, ID) where c2 is not null and c3 is not null;

This index will be extremely small (and fast) and will be updated only when new records are inserted with not null values.
To have the optimizer use this index, you need to repeat the index condition in the query you want to optimize:
select ID, c2, c3, c4, c5
from t1
where c2 is not null and c3 is not null
and c2 = 100 and c3 = 'x'
order by c2, c3, c4, ID;


Filtered indexes can't be used with parameterised plans (because the parameter might not meet the filter). There's a show plan warning about it, under Unmatched Indexes.
